# Telegram получить id пользователя имея username

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

как можно получить id пользователя, который не писал в чат боту, и имея только его @username, либо имея его id, который прислал другой пользователь в чат боту

Answer (score 1):

По моему сие не возможно, так как нет у телеграмма метода как у ВКонтакте users.get где можешь передать username и получить в ответ id

Comment: я тоже так думаю, но есть в телеграме бот один ( не буду давать его чтобы не рекламировать грязные вещи) так вот у него есть поиск пользователей, и в нем можно найти абсолютно любого, поиск по пересланному сообщению понятно как работает, а вот как он находит по логину или по id не понятно, ради интереса создал новый аккаунт, так он нашел его id, хотя с того аккаунта не писал тому боту

Comment: @get_any_telegram_id_bot  кстати говоря вот бот который ищет это

Comment: Этот бот какой-то косячный, к примеру ни одного юзера по номеру телефона не нашёл. Но вот по username как-то определяет, а если определяет значит реально. Значит тебе не на stackoverflow а в Google, я нашёл пару статей, но что-то у меня не получается повторить..